# Interpretation of inequality between 2 stopping times.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ be a filtration of $\sigma$-fields, i.e., $\mathcal{F}_{n} \subset \mathcal{F}_{n+1}$ for every $n \ge$ 1. Let $\tau_{1}$ be a stopping time, i.e, a random variable such that the event $\lbrace \tau_{1} \le n\rbrace$ $\in$ $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ for every $n \ge$ 1.

I am given: if $\tau_{1} \le \tau_{2}$ then $\lbrace \tau_{2} \le n \rbrace \subset \lbrace \tau_{1} \le n \rbrace$.

I am having trouble understanding why $\lbrace \tau_{2} \le n \rbrace \subset \lbrace \tau_{1} \le n \rbrace$ and what it means for one stopping time to be smaller than another.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$\tau_1\leq \tau_2$ means $\tau_1(\omega)\leq \tau_2(\omega)$ for all $\omega$. From this inequality, you can get $\Omega=\{\tau_1\leq \tau_2\}=\cup_{k\geq 1}\{\tau_1\leq k\leq \tau_2\}$. Then, it follows that $\{\tau_2\leq n\}=\left[\cup_{k\geq 1}\{\tau_1\leq k\leq \tau_2\}\right]\cap \{\tau_2\leq n\}=\cup_{1\leq k\leq n}\{\tau_1\leq k\leq \tau_2\leq n\}\subset \cup_{k\leq n}\{\tau_1\leq k\}=\{\tau_1\leq n\}$.

Comment: Thanks! Intuitively though, does $\lbrace \tau_{2} \le n \rbrace \subset \lbrace \tau_{1} \le n \rbrace$ make sense because, for every $\omega \in \Omega$, the "amount" of $\omega$'s in the event $\lbrace \tau_{2} \le n \rbrace$ will always have less or equal amounts of the same $\omega$'s in the event $\lbrace \tau_{1} \le n \rbrace$ because $\tau_{2}$ will, if the inequality were strict ($\tau_{1} < \tau_{2}$) say, always "hit" $n$ first, before $\tau_{1}$ "hits" $n$?

Comment: @lost Why complicate things needlessly like that?

Comment: @Did Maybe because I am not a native English speaker, it is easier for me to write the answer in symbolic language rather than in words. I am sorry for that.

Comment: Offtopic I am afraid. Just like the decomposition $\{\tau_1\leq \tau_2\}=\bigcup\limits_{k\geq 1}\{\tau_1\leq k\leq \tau_2\}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I have written some things needless here. Thank you for your reminder.